# Factor $2^{15}-1$ into product of two smaller positive integers.

Tags: factoring

Let $ab=n=2^{15}-1$. We know that $n$ is odd, so either $a$, $b$ or both are odd.

Suppose there is just one of $a$ or $b$ that is odd.

$$\begin{align}
n&=(2k+1)(2q)\\
&=4kq+2q\\
&=2(2kq+q)
\end{align}$$

This contradicts the fact that $n$ is odd, so both $a$ and $b$ must be odd.

$$\begin{align}
n&=(2k+1)(2q+1)\\
&=4kq+2k+2q+1\\
&=2(2kq+k+q)+1\\
\frac{n-1}{2}&=2kq+k+q
\end{align}$$

Solving for $k$ gives us

$$k=\frac{n-1-2q}{2+4q}$$

**Now we need to get one value of $q$ such that $k$ is an integer**

Trying values of $q$ starting from $0$ gives the value $q=3$ and $k=2340$, so $a=4681$ and $b=7$.

---

But I don't like the last step of just trying numbers. Is there a sistematic way to get the answer without just guessing values for $q$ or $k$?

Comment: Hint:  $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

Comment: both $a$ and $b$ must be odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $$2^{15}-1=(2^5)^3-1$$ and $$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Just use the identities  $$a^3-b^3 =(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2) $$ $$a^5-b^5 =(a-b)(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4) $$ and see what you get. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is this pattern also true for $a^n-b^n$?

Comment: @Garmekain We have $$(a^n-b^n) = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + \cdots + ab^{n-2} + b^{n-1}) $$ for all $n \in \mathbb N $.

Comment: @Garmekain You can up vote and accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

We can do better without any calculation.

$(2^n-1)_{n\ge 1}$ is a strongly divisibility sequence, hence $\gcd(2^3-1,2^5-1)=2^{\gcd(3,5)}-1=1$. It follows that
$$
2^{15}-1=(2^3-1)(2^5-1)\frac{2^{15}-1}{(2^3-1)(2^5-1)}.
$$

Comment: ... and as it turns ou that last fraction is a prime as well

Comment: Ah xD I didn't check it, thanks :)